# Using Bi-cubic Interpolation

Tags: image, image-processing

I read about it on Wikipedia, theory sounds good, but I don't know to apply to practice.

I have an small example like this one:

Original Image Matrix

```
1 2
3 4
```

If I want to double size the image, then the new matrix is

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Now, the fun part is how to transfer old values in original matrix to the new matrix, I intend to do like this

```
1 x 2 x
x x x x
3 x 4 x
x x x x
```

Then applying the Bi cubic Interpolation on it (at this moment just forget about using 16 neighbor pixel, I don't have enough space to demonstrate such a large matrix here).

Now my questions are:

1. Do I do the data transferring (from old to new matrix) right? If not, what should it look like?

2. What should be the value of x variables in the new matrix? to me , this seems correct because at least we have some values to do the calculation instead of x notations.

```
1 1 2 2 
1 1 2 2
3 3 4 4 
3 3 4 4
```

3. Will all of the pixels in new matrix be interpolated? Because the pixels at the boundary do not have enough neighbor pixels to perform the calculation.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interpolation means estimating a value for points that don't physically exist. You need to start with a coordinate system, so let's just use two incrementing integers for X position and Y position.

```
0, 0    1, 0
0, 1    1, 1
```

Your output requires 4x4 pixels which should be spaced at 0.5 intervals instead of the 1.0 intervals of the input:

```
-0.25,-0.25   0.25,-0.25   0.75,-0.25   1.25,-0.25
-0.25, 0.25   0.25, 0.25   0.75, 0.25   1.25, 0.25
-0.25, 0.75   0.25, 0.75   0.75, 0.75   1.25, 0.75
-0.25, 1.25   0.25, 1.25   0.75, 1.25   1.25, 1.25
```

None of the coordinates in the output exist in the input, so they'll all need to be interpolated.

The offset of the first coordinate of -0.25 is chosen so that the first and last coordinate will be equal distances from the edges of the input, and is calculated by the difference between the output and input intervals divided by 2. For example if you wanted a 10x zoom the interval is 0.1, the initial offset is (0.1-1)/2 and the points would be (-0.45, -0.35, -0.25, -0.15, ... 1.35, 1.45).

The Bicubic algorithm will require data for points outside of the original image. The easiest solution comes when you use a [premultiplied alpha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premultiplied_alpha) representation for your pixels, then you can just use (0,0,0,0) as the value for anything outside the image boundaries.

Comment: oh can you be more specific about this part " let's just use two incrementing integers for X position and Y position.", I'm sorry but i don't understand what you meant...

Comment: @Aptos, what I meant was rather than labeling the points "1,2,3,4" I wanted to use an X,Y coordinate system. The picture after the paragraph details exactly what I meant.

Comment: oh I see.. :) how silly me.. hhmmmh, but i still have 02 more unclear points here, the first one is why the output matrix should be spaced at 0.5 interval and not be 1?Because if I choose interval =1, I will I have a bigger image? the above output example is zoom x2, so if it is x3, is the interval changed? How will it be changed? The second unclear point is that now, for example i want to calculate point at (-0.25,-.025), all of its neighbor is zero, so basically the whole is image will be white... I think i misunderstood something here..

Comment: @Aptos each point in the output must come from a point in the input. When the spacing is 0.5 the zoom will be 1/0.5, or 2x. For a 3x zoom you'd use a spacing of 1/3. As for pixels on the edge, the bicubic calculation requires values for pixels +/-2 on either side of the coordinate, in this case from -2.25 to 1.75. Obviously you won't have data between -2.25 and 0, but you still have 2 valid points 0 and 1 between 0 and 1.75 and that's enough. I really wanted to go into more detail in this answer but didn't have time, I might edit it later.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you get the new locations' coordinate?(-0.25->1.25) and what will happend if the space interval is 0.1? (aka 10x zoom). When shrinking an image, the space interval will > 1 ? Thank you very much

Comment: @Aptos the beginning and ending coordinates are chosen so that they're equally spaced from the beginning and ending of the input. I've obviously made a mistake since -0.25 is 0.25 away from 0 and 1.75 is 0.75 away from 1, so I'll have to fix the answer. And Bicubic is a poor choice when you're shrinking an image unless you use it as a filter rather than an interpolator.

Comment: Thank you, and i noticed that the coordinates of new points make it become non linear with the old ones, so if you imagine, this old point now is now in the center of a square that have vertexes are new points, so how the calculation can be made when they are not linear?. And how can be smartly when choosing the beginning and the ending coordinates? Is there any formula here? Thank you very much.